# What is the real nature of inline keyword in relation to linkages?

Tags: c++, inline, linkage

I have a serious problem to reconcile the "inline concept" with "linkage" with my humble knowledge:

- I've heard we can use `extern` to access "a non-static entity"
  (like an entity that is NOT declared with static key) from other
  files
  = YES! I GOT THIS
- They say we can use `inline` to make a function or variable
  appear in a "header file" and so that it can be accessed across multiple
  translation units
  = YES! I GOT THIS
- They also say "an inline entity" can have either "internal or
  external linkage"
  = I DIDN'T GET IT

( [A: Inline functions with internal linkage?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2398105) - This where I first heard about an inline entity with "internal linkage" )

An inline entity can be accessed from anywhere across multiple translation units, so doesn't it mean that "an inline entity" should always have "external linkage" as granted?

What is the point of "an inline entity" which can be accessed from anywhere across multiple translation units and has "INTERNAL linkage"?

Any answer or any confirmation that I was wrong in any point would be appreciated.

Comment: I have never heard of inline entity with internal linkage. Where did you find this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2398105/22196023 - this where I first heard "internal linkage"

Comment: inline keyword basically means, linker you can pick any definition (implementation) of this function for linking... I as a developer promise that all versions that may be encountered across multiple translation units are actually ALL the same version.

Comment: The question you reference is about C. The `inline` keyword does not work the same way in C++ as it does in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer you've linked relates to C's `inline`, which works slightly differently. However, in either language, `inline` does not affect linkage.

`inline` on a function makes it an *[inline function](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.inline#def:function,inline)*. By default, any free function has [external linkage](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#def:linkage,external), which basically means that all functions `f` declared in multiple translation units refers to the same `f`. `static` would make make the functions have [internal linkage](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#def:linkage,internal), which means that every translation unit has its own `f`.

```cpp
// inline function with external linkage
inline void f() { }

// also an inline function with external linkage
extern inline void g() { }

// inline function with internal linkage
static inline void h() { }

namespace { // anonymous namespace
// also an inline function with internal linkage
inline void k() { }
}
```

> An inline entity can be accessed from any where across multiple translation units, so doesn't it mean that "an inline entity" should always have "external linkage" as granted?

A function doesn't have to be an *inline function* to be accessible in multiple TUs. `inline` just means that it can be *defined* in multiple TUs, not just declared, and this won't cause any linker errors (all definitions must be identical). In other words, the [one-definition rule is relaxed for *inline functions*](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#14.1). And yes, as stated above, free functions have external linkage by default, even if they are `inline`.

> What is the point of "an inline entity" which can be accessed from anywhere across multiple translation units and has "INTERNAL linkage"?

None. If it's accessible in multiple translation units, then it shouldn't have internal linkage. The benefit of internal linkage is that you can define it differently with the same name in different TUs. `static inline` in headers is an anti-pattern from C, which is motivated by the problem that unlike in C++, if a function isn't inlined, the linker will looks for an `extern` definition in some object file instead, which may not exist.

```cpp
// assuming all of the following are defined in a header ...

// C: if f() isn't inlined, we get linker errors
//    to solve this, declare an extern inline definition in some source file
// C++: if f() isn't inlined, this is okay; the linker will pick one of N definitions,
//      which are automatically generated in the non-inlined case
inline void f() {}

// C: if h() isn't inlined, duplicates get emitted into multiple TUs
// C++: same, but this is stupid and avoidable; don't use 'static inline'
static inline void h() {}
```